# Can Xindy and MakeIndex coexist?

Tags: xindy, makeindex

Is it possible to use Xindy and MakeIndex in the same document without fear of collisions? The reason for doing so is that there is a dearth of good documentation on using Xindy for general indexing purposes, but there is good documentation on using Xindy in tandem with the `glossaries` package, so I'd like to generate the glossary with Xindy, but use MakeIndex for all other indexing purposes.

Comment: If they don't try to use or generate the same files I don't see why it should be a problem.

Comment: It is easier, actually. I'd prefer to use `xindy` for both but haven't gotten around to figuring out how, so I make do with `makeindex` for the index and muddle through.